# Laravel notifications saved to different schema

Tags: laravel, notifications

How would I force different notifications to be saved in different schemas.

For example, I have two notification tables `client.botifications` and `business.notifications` in my DB.
I want all notifications to be saved to the Business schema with the exception of one notification, which I would like to be saved to the Client Schema.

Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 0):

Some presumptions must be made, i assume you a default database connection and in this case a `client` connection to support your secondary scheme. If it is the other way around interchange them accordingly. And you notifiable is a user.

If you read through the notification logic, at some point it calls `$notifiable->notifications()->create();` This is on the notifiable class, which gets it `notification()` relationship method, from [this trait](https://github.com/illuminate/notifications/blob/master/HasDatabaseNotifications.php). To avoid all the users operation, being saved on the wrong connection, i would just change the connection when you call the notify, when it should be saved on the client connection.

```
$user = User::find($someUser);
$user->setConnection('client');
$user->notify(YourClientNotification());
```